# Android Preload Recycleview Contents

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, preload, android-cardview

I have a three tab interface setup using a ViewPager. In the 3rd tab, I have a CardView which can expand/retract onclick to reveal more information. Inside the CardView is a RecyclerView which is inflated with a bunch of data.

The first time the app opens and the CardView is expanded, the expand animation is quite laggy but afterwards, it can be expanded/retracted smoothly. The RecyclerView data can also be updated with no problem.

Is there a way to somehow load/cache the data upon opening the app so the lagg does not occur.

Sorry if question is poor, just starting android development.
Thanks

Layout on third tab:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/SF_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SF_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/SF_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The data which is used to inflate the recyclerView is a list of objects each with 2 float variables. Roughly length ~50.

The xml used to inflate each item:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="lorem"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="ipsom"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code to expand/retract the cardView simply animated changing the height of SF_frame to reveal more elements of the RecyclerView and it is this first reveal which is laggy.

Comment: What kind of data and how they are retreived? If there are images (I think they might require a lot of processor time for beginners) try to use some library with async loading (first hit try http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the info is just a bunch of numbers, which are calculated in another funciton. I think the lagg is not so much fetching the data but rather just displaying a bunch of hidden views for the first time

Comment: Can you add your Cardview xml first? then we should know where the problem might be... I don't think preloading data is smart way. Only if there are really huge data.

Comment: I have added in the relevant code. Again thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Ok, your layouting is pretty bad, will write you correct one in answer later... So problem might only be animation or the data themself. I think data is more probable, since animation is lagging only once. Can you also past some simplified code of how TextViews are filled? You will probably need to fill them asynchronously (AsyncTask is best for this)

Answer (score 1):

Resolve your Layouting as first:
Use `sp` only with texts and `dp` for other dimensions (width, height, margins, paddings etc.). For texts it is recommended to use at least `android:textsize="12sp"`. Look at the `android:gravity` attribute instead of `android:layout_gravity` so you don't have to use parent layout just to center it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/SF_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <!-- No need to use LinearLayout since only one child is used -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/SF_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In this layout, if you are expanding RecyclerView, it is possible that new views are being instantiated (`RecyclerView.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder` and `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder`) are called mulitple times.
In fact switching to that Tab is also a little bit delayed, but it is clearly visible on animation. (you are expandig from about 3 items to maybe 20 or so, I don't know how rest of your layout looks)

and second:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="lorem"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="ipsom"
        android:textSize="8sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If filling these 2 `TextViews` is so terribly slow, that you are experiencing hickups. Then you probably doing very very complex math operations (try to simplify them if possible) or you are somehow downloading data synchronously and waiting for results.

Please have a look at [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and use it while binding data... You can use it something like this (modify by yourself):

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private TextView view;

    MyAsyncTask(TextView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // display progressbar or something
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do heavyweight operation here
        String result = heavyWeightOperation(params);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        // hide progressbar or something
        if (view != null) {
            view.setText(s);
        }
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow somebody upvoted this :) Now you can forget `AsyncTask` and use `AsyncTaskLoader`, `Rx` constructs or something more relevant